# CMake build error with added header file - fatal error: file not found

Tags: cmake, header-files, fatal-error

I used CMake to build C++ source files in Ubuntu 14.04.

I has a main source file. This includes a header file, which contains a function in another source file.

My main source file is DisplayImage.cpp, and my header file is Camera.h with a source file Camera.cpp.

Every file is located in one folder. And I have a CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp Camera.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage  ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

When I execute the command `cmake .` in the terminal, it configures successfully. After that, I execute command `make`, and I get a fatal error:

```
fatal error: Camera.h: No such file or directory
```

Please help me. Is my CmakeLists.txt wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need `include_directories()` to specify in which ones the compiler should look to.

Comment: that means i should put header and it's file cpp in a another directory, then include_directories() in cmakelist.txt

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) to tell CMake to associate specific *include directories* containing your headers with the `DisplayImage` target. Assuming your `Camera.h` file is in the same directory as `Camera.cpp`, you can use [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) to specify this directory. You should also add the `${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}` here, as shown in the "Using OpenCV with CMake" [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp Camera.cpp )
target_include_directories(DisplayImage PRIVATE 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} 
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Note: it is good CMake practice to *always* specify the scoping argument (e.g. `PUBLIC`, `PRIVATE`, or `INTERFACE`) in the `target_*` commands.