# CMake file in subdirectory cannot access external library

Tags: opencv, cmake

My project structure looks like this:

```
Project
  | Dependency
      functions.cpp
      functions.h
  | DisplayImage.cpp
```

I want to use opencv in functions.cpp. It works when I use opencv functions in DisplayImage, but when I include opencv2/imgproc.hpp in functions.h I get a 'file not found error'.

My CMakeLists looks like this in the root:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(DisplayImage)

set("OpenCV_DIR" "~/opencv/build")
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(Dependency)

add_executable(DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp)

target_link_libraries(DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS})

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependency")
include_directories("~/CppLibraries/eigen-3.3.7/Eigen")
```

and the CMakeLists.txt file in the Dependency directory contains:

```
add_library(Dependency functions.cpp functions.h)
```

Why can opencv2/imgproc.hpp not be found in functions.h?

This is the error message I get:

```
$ cmake --build .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/bn/Documents/C++/opencv_playground/build
Scanning dependencies of target DisplayImage
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable DisplayImage
[ 50%] Built target DisplayImage
[ 75%] Building CXX object Dependency/CMakeFiles/Dependency.dir/functions.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/bn/Documents/C++/opencv_playground/Dependency/functions.cpp:1:
/Users/bn/Documents/C++/opencv_playground/Dependency/functions.h:1:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/imgproc.hpp'
      file not found
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [Dependency/CMakeFiles/Dependency.dir/functions.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Dependency/CMakeFiles/Dependency.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the **complete** error message into your question post. Also, the use of the `~` path shortcut has been known to cause issues with CMake, so consider writing out the **full** path instead.

Comment: In addition, you haven't added the OpenCV header directories as *include directories* in your CMake (with `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS`), so I'm surprised any of the OpenCV headers are found **at all**. See the OpenCV instructions [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html)

Comment: There is a response to a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794074/cmake-build-error-with-added-header-file-fatal-error-file-not-found).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I built opencv from source, which directory do I have to list in the include_directories command? There aren't any header files in the build/include directory.

Comment: Because you use `find_package(OpenCV ...`, the `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable **should** be populated, if the OpenCV was indeed found correctly. So `include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})` should be enough to add the OpenCV headers to your project.

Comment: The weird thing is that DisplayImage.cpp cannot be built if I remove the find_package command, so the executable target does find the opencv library, its just that the subdirectory file doesnt find it.

Comment: If I want to use a library in a subdirectory, do I also have to include the find_package and target_link_libraries command in the CMakeList file of the subdirectory?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to determine *why* the headers are visible in one directory, but not in another. For example, it would be helpful to know **where** the OpenCV repository resides on your machine *relative to* your CMake project, and whether or not you **installed** OpenCV after you built it from source. But yes, if the `Dependency` target uses OpenCV, you should use `target_link_libraries(Dependency PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS})` there as well.

Comment: The target_link_libraries command was missing in the CMakeLists file of the subdirectory. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purpose you can add following lines in your CMakeLists.txt after "find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )"

```
message(STATUS "cv libs: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "include_path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

when you do "cmake .", in the terminal, it will prints out all opencv libs and include paths.

Answer (score 0):

In the CMakeLists.txt file in the Dependency subdirectory, I needed to include target_link_libraries(Dependency PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS}), so the CMakeLists file looks like:

```
add_library(Dependency functions.cpp functions.h)
target_link_libraries(Dependency PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```